electron forgeでvue 3を用いたアプリのセットアップガイドでelectronアプリが起動しないエラー
electron forge + vite + vue.js + typescriptの構成でデスクトップアプリケーションをセットアップしようとしています。
electron forge 公式ガイド
https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/vue-3
参考サイト
https://www.jenuel.dev/blog/Electron-Forge-Vite-VueJS-Easier-Way
実行手順
electron forgeの公式ガイド等を参考に、以下の手順で必要なテンプレート等をインストールしました。
yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=vite-typescript
yarn add -D @vitejs/plugin-vue
yarn add vue

その後ガイド通りにvue3用に生成されたフォルダの内容を一部変更し、下記のようなフォルダ構成になりました。
app-name
-src
--App.vue（新規作成）
--main.ts
--preload.ts
--renderer.ts（書き換え）
-index.html（書き換え）
-vite.renderer.config.ts（書き換え）
（一部抜粋）

その後、electronアプリを起動したところエラーが発生し起動しませんでした。
yarn start

発生したエラー
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at Object.closeBundle (app-name\vite.preload.config.ts:100:37)  
    at file:///app-name/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25544:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///app-name/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25472:9)
    at async Object.close (file:///app-name/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:26726:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

vue3やviteのバージョンを落としたりしてみましたが、解決しません。
あまりelectron forgeは主流では内容でエラーの解決策等発見できませんでした。
手順の誤りなどお気づきのことがありましたらお教えください。
